# in Tomcat thread pool executor, we will specify the thread size, right? is that thread count included in tomcat thread count?

Tags: threadpool

As far as i know, when ever tomcat server is started, it will start around 250 threads.
Assume, we specify 25 is the thread size in thread pool executor. so now total threads in tomcat is 250 + 25 or just 250 threads in which 25 threads will also be included?

regards,
Sathish

Answer (score 0):

The executor will create the number of threads specified in minSpareThreads parameter. Connectors may create other threads if they are not assigned to use the executor. In addition to this Tomcat will create threads for its internal purposes.